# Unable to exit from while loop

Tags: java, arrays, element

```
Integer[][] a = new Integer[3][3];
int value1=1;

while(a !=null) {   
    System.out.println("Please enter the value of indexes");
    i=input.nextInt();
    j=input.nextInt();

    int value= input.nextInt();
    if(!(i<0||i>2 && j<0 || j>2)) {
        if(a[i][j]== null) {
            a[i][j]=value;
            System.out.printf("value of a[%d][%d] =%d",i,j,a[i][j]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Index already has value");
        }
    }
    else {
        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

i have made a check against a in while i want to leave the loop when all the elements of loop gets a value but its not working

Answer (score 1):

`a != null` will be true at all points after the statement `Integer[][] a = new Integer[3][3];` unless you explicitly set `a = null`. `a != null` doesn't check anything about the contents of the array; it only checks that the array exists.

If you want the loop to stop when all entries of `a` are non-null, you can use `while (Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(null))` instead. This will check over the array at the start of each `while` loop iteration and stop if it does not contain any null values.

---

For a more efficient option, you could also create a counter initialized to `a.length` and decrement it whenever you fill in a slot of the array.

```
Integer[][] a = new Integer[3][3];
int value1=1;
int remaining = a.length;

while (remaining > 0) {   
    System.out.println("Please enter the value of indexes");
    i=input.nextInt();
    j=input.nextInt();

    int value= input.nextInt();
    if(!(i<0||i>2 && j<0 || j>2)) {
        if(a[i][j]== null) {
            a[i][j]=value;
            remaining--;
```